# Post to anonymous user's Facebook Wall with rules

Tags: rules, social-network

I wonder what is the best way to implement post to User's wall for anonymous users. All solutions I came across seem to require creation of a Drupal User Account (using FB Connect) first.

I need a rules action that automatically asks for permission to post and then posts immediately, without creating a Drupal User Account, fetching any additional information and especially without requiring the user to connect manually in advance.

Thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what have you tried, so how can we know if we're suggesting some new solution? Anyway you could try Facebook Autopost https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost if it isn't on you personal "All solutions I came across" list

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

I apologize for not giving details. It does not seem to be possbile with FBOauth + Facebook Rules as post to wall action does not fire if user is not connected manually. Drupal for Facebook also misses this feature.

When using FB Autopost make sure to set publishing permissions in the module settings and create correct entity with rules, then it works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome! I also had lots of troubles with the "post to Facebook modules". Some time ago I tried "Drupal for Facebook", which I think it's the most complete Facebook module for Drupal, but it's also very complex and so I ended using fb_autopost :)